# How to separate string in PHP

Tags: php

I have 20 lines of string seperated with "\n"

I have 2 fields to put this string into

$field1 is limited to 10 lines of string

$field2 can store unlimited lines of string

How do I run a php code to seperate the string into 2 fields.

The 1st-10th line will be stored in $field1.

The 11th-20th line will carry over to $field2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$array = explode("\n", $text);
$field1 = implode("\n", array_slice($array, 0, 10));
$field2 = implode("\n", array_slice($array, 10));
```

Answer (score 2):

- do an `explode` by `"\n"`,
- iterate through the resulting array
- put the first 10 results in `$field1`
- put the rest in `$field2`

Answer (score 1):

```
$file_array = file($file_name);

$int = 10;

foreach ($file_array as $line)
{
if($int >=0){
array_push($field1,$line);
$int--;
}else{
array_push($field2,$line);
}


}
```

You can always trim the lines to get rid of the \n .

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

preg_match('/^((?:[^\n]*\n){10})([\w\W]*)$/', $str, $matches);

$field1 = $matches[1];
$field2 = $matches[2];  

?>
```